# What is this check mark on xml layout file about

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

In Android studio one of my xml layout files show this check mark.
What is this check mark on xml layout file about

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have bookmarked this file (pressed Ctr+F11 or F11 ).

see [Navigating with Bookmarks](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/navigating-with-bookmarks.html#d2171954e15)

Comment: ctrl + click (while adding debugger) resulted that checkmark in java file.